# Why is the covariace of a vector writen like this?

Tags: covariance

Say I have a white noise process $w_a$.
Why is the co variance matrix of the vector written as $E(w_a*w_a^T)$?

Isn't the expected value equal to $E(x) =\int xf(x) $?

So for example isn't the first component of the covariance matrix going to be $E(w_{a1}^2) =\int w_{a1}^2f(w_{a1}) $ so how is that equal to $\sigma_{a1}^2$?

Comment: If you intend $w_a$ to be a vector, then just what do you mean by "$w_a^2$"?

Comment: @whuber, thanks! I calrified that it was just the first component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the covariance matrix by $\Sigma = \text{E}(w_aw_a^T)$. As you note, the $i$th entry of the diagonal of the covariance matrix should be $\text{Var}(w_{ai}) = \sigma_{ai}^2 $. Since we're dealing with a white noise process, we assume $\text{E}(w_{ai}) = 0$ for each $i$. So
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(w_{ai}) &= \text{E}(w_{ai}^2) - \text{E}(w_{ai})^2 \\
& =\text{E}(w_{ai}^2) \\
& = \Sigma_{ii}.
\end{align*}
$$
This shows that the formula produces the correct values for the diagonal. Now the off-diagonal entries should be
$$
\begin{align*}
\Sigma_{ij} & = \text{Cov}(w_{ai},w_{aj}) \\
& = \text{E}(w_{ai}w_{aj}) - \text{E}(w_{ai})\text{E}(w_{aj}) \\
& = \text{E}(w_{ai}w_{aj}),
\end{align*}
$$
which is precisely the $ij$th entry of the matrix $\text{E}(w_aw_a^T)$. So that's where the formula comes from.